# Can't run apps on Ubuntu - PATH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I'm trying to install apps on Ubuntu and I can, but I can't run them. I install them using "pip3 install appname".
When I try to run them, nothing happens.
Everytime I install a python app, I get the error:
It says `"The script streamlink (app name) is installed in '/home/bob/.local/bin' which is not on PATH."`

I've tried editing "/etc/environment" and inserting "/home/bob/.local/bin" but nothing happens. I still can't run my python app.

Note: this is a fresh Ubuntu install.

Comment: What is the value of your $PATH? (`echo $PATH`).

Comment: I've solved. I've checked my path. It was "/home/.local/bin" instead of "/home/username/.local/bin"

Comment: Just changing to "/home/$user/.local/bin" solved.